# legacy.js throwing error " Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when try to open jquery UI dialog on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup code where I am opening a jquery UI dialog on click of a button. I am Rendering page inside dialog via ajax call.

```js
$(".clikablePopupLink a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("Test", "Test")",
    success: function(result, status, xhr) {
      $('#dialog-innercomapre').html(result);
      $('#dialog-innercomapre').dialog('open');
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, "slow");

      list.forEach(function(item) {
        $('.innerContentPopupComapre').find('[data-title="' + item + '"]').addClass('selected');
        $('.innerContentPopupComapre').find('[data-title="' + item + '"] button').addClass('rotateBtn_inner');
      });

      listArray.forEach(function(item) {
        var html1 = '<div id="' + item.productID + '" class="relPos titleMargin w3-margin-bottom w3-col l3 m4 s4"><div class="w3-white titleMargin"><a class="selectedItemCloseBtn_inner w3-closebtn cursor">&times</a><p id="' + item.productID + '" class="titleMargin1">' + item.displayTitle + '</p></div></div>';
        $('.comparePan_inner').append(html1);
      });
    }
  })
});
```

I am getting Below error...

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>               at String.split (legacy.js?cdv=558210432:81)
>               at String.split (legacy.js?cdv=558210432:84)
>               at String.split (legacy.js?cdv=558210432:84)
>               at String.split (legacy.js?cdv=558210432:84)

If I remove legacy.js I get jquery-1.12.0.min.js error

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Comment: The 'Maximum call stack' error means you've somehow created infinite recursion. There doesn't seem to be any reason for this in the code you've posted, so check the logic flow in your other functions.